# Findbugs reports Load of known null value while validating constructor argument

Tags: constructor, null, findbugs

Upon scanning following code with findbugs, it reports Dodgy code:NP: Load of known null value in new ....(at line where new Exception is thrown)

Sometimes it is required to check null before initializing an object.
Why is this considered "dodgy"??

```
public class Employee{

  @Valid
  private Department dept;

  @JsonCreator
  public Employee(@JsonProperty(value = "department", required = true) Department aDepartment)
      throws EmpServiceException{
    if (aDepartment == null) {
      throw new EmpServiceException(aDepartment, "Invalid Request");
    }
    this.dept= aDepartment;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that FindBugs is pointing out that the line where you throw the exception

```
throw new EmpServiceException(aDepartment, "Invalid Request");
```

is equivalent to

```
throw new EmpServiceException(null, "Invalid Request");
```

and wants you to use the latter. Is the first argument for that `EmpServiceException` constructor annotated with `@NonNull`?

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely it.